# Magento newsletter confirmation email sent on placed order

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I have a really bizarre situation where when I am logged in to my magento store, if I place an order I get an automated email for newsletter signup confirmation.

If I place a guest order I don't get this.

Comment: are you using any extension for checkout or using default magento onpage checkout?

Comment: are you receiving a newsletter confirmation along with order email or not receiving order email at all and just receving a newsletter one?